# How can I get a list of token spending allowance for a wallet address?

Tags: erc-20, allowance

Let's say I am an end-user who has been testing dapps here and there and I've approved multiple tokens spending for my wallet for different dapps.

Is there an easy way for me to get the list of which contract (dapp) is allowed to spend which token for my wallet?

Comment: Yes, if you have the total list of tokens that you have in your wallet (i.e., the contract address of each token).

Comment: So it's necessary to know the tokens before hand then? Does that mean I'd need to kind of scan for erc20 transactions, determine which tokens have moved and then look for the allowance?

Comment: There might be a way without it, one sec...

Comment: @goodvibration Just wanted to ping you in case you had a solution

Answer (score 0):

My tool [Revoke.cash](https://revoke.cash) checks for all the allowances that you gave to someone else. The code for Revoke is [open source](https://github.com/RevokeCash/revoke.cash) so if you could look at the code to inspect how it works in case you'd need to do this programmatically.